# Как имея одну точку входа в приложение (один файл) найти неиспользуемый код в остальных файлах?

Tags: golang, рефакторинг, code-analyst

Собственно имеется приложение, которое является вынесенной из монолита логикой, микросервис. Главный файл, кроме тестов, один, все сопутствующее это скопированные директориями модули. Но в них куча лишней и ненужной логики. Я выпиливаю все это вручную, но там очень много всего. Есть ли какой-то метод найти все неиспользуемые главным файлом структуры, методы интерфейсы?

Comment: Если что, по файлам в го мало что работает.  Минимальная единица компиляции — это пакет.

Answer (score 1):

Бесплатный и свободный инструмент статического анализа
[`staticcheck`](https://staticcheck.io) умеет
находить неиспользованный код.  Пример:

```sh
$ nl -b a ./tmp.go 
     1  package main
     2  
     3  func main() {
     4      used()
     5  }
     6  
     7  func used() {}
     8  
     9  func unused() {}
$ staticcheck ./tmp.go 
tmp.go:9:6: func unused is unused (U1000)

Run 'staticcheck -explain <check>' or visit https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks for documentation on checks.
$
```

Comment: спасибо, похоже, то что нужно

Comment: не знаю правильно ли я все делаю, но после всех исправлений, этот статикчек отработал и ничего не показал о неиспользуемом коде, я наверное неправильно сформулировал вопрос, мне надо чтобы было только необходимое для файла, который компилируется в бинарник, остальное я хочу убрать. то есть неиспользуемые функции это имелось ввиду все те, которые не нужны для компиляции и работы этого файла.

Comment: @JohnRoget  Прочитайте мой комментарий под вашим вопросом.  Большинство инструментов в го работают с пакетами, а не с файлами.  Вы можете выделить всё, что нужно, в пакет, после чего вызвать `staticcheck` из корня проекта, указав все пакеты проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую golangci-lint. Практически все возможные проверки в одном линтере.
Кроме того иногда бывает полезен gocritic (но сборка его с полтычка  не пройдёт -- читайте инструкцию на сайте).